# Difference between two statements

Tags: meaning, differences

Difference between these two sentences:

1. I was the first person to leave.
2. I left first.

---

1. You will be the first to know
2. You will know first

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better on ELL.


Answer (score 1):

The first sentence implies some sort of significance to be the first to leave. The second is quite factual and just a statement stating that the person left first.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a meaningful difference between either pair, though "you will be the first to know" is much more common than "you will know first."